# MYSQL Count where active across tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

```
person
-----------
person_id, active

person_team
-----------
person_id, team_id, active

team
-----------
team_id, active
```

I'd like to get the count on `teams` from each `person` where `active` is true in each table.

So far I have:

```
SELECT t.id, t.title, t.created_timestamp, COUNT(p_t.tag_id) AS count
FROM team t
LEFT JOIN 
    person_team p_t ON p_t.team_id = t.id AND p_t.active = 1
WHERE 
    t.active = 1
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER BY t.title
```

This gets the count where team and person - team are active, but doesn't take into account whether person is active. Should I use a sub query or another type of join?

Comment: Provide some sample table data

Comment: How can you select `t.title, t.created_timestamp` in select when it is not in group by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `person` table in a join, and count a column from that table:

```
SELECT t.id, t.title, t.created_timestamp, COUNT(p.id) AS count
FROM team t
LEFT JOIN 
    person_team p_t ON p_t.team_id = t.id AND p_t.active = 1
LEFT JOIN 
    person p ON p_t.person_id = p.id AND p.active = 1
WHERE 
    t.active = 1
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER BY t.title
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a inner join on sub select for get the columns not in group by

```
select k.id, t.title, t.created_timestamp, k.count from 
 (  SELECT t.id  COUNT(p_t.tag_id) AS count
FROM team t
LEFT JOIN 
    person_team p_t ON p_t.team_id = t.id AND p_t.active = 1
WHERE 
    t.active = 1
GROUP BY t.id ) k
inner join team t on t.id = k.id
```